# How to place a 100% height div above some more content?

Tags: html, css

I have a landing page with a full screen image as a stage. Then you can scroll down for more content. And on the bottom is a footer.

```
landingpage
    fullscreen image (height 100%)
    content below that image
footer
```

How can I accomplish that?

For the image height to work I need to set the landingpage height to 100%. But then the footer goes below the image over the other content inside the landingpage.

If I make the image absolute positioned and it's height to 100%, the content inside the landingpage goes over the image.

EDIT: As requested some code. I want to make the stage's height 100%.

```
<div id="landing">
    <div id="stage"></div>
    Some more content...
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: nice concept now show us the code ;)

Comment: actually if you work with header/content/footer you may should use divs and set the background image or place the image to the div. than you can span the image to 100%. Guess your problem is that you dont set with and hight of body and rest of your content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `<section>` tag with css `height: 100vh`

```
<body id="landing">
    <header></header> <!-- navigation or logo + full-width -->
    <section id="stage">
        <img src="" alt=""> <!-- absolute -->
    </section> <!-- 100% height + full-width -->
    <section></section> <!--other content + full-width-->
    <footer></footer> <!--full-width-->
</body>
```

More about [Css Units](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrduUUdxBSY)

Answer (score 0):

use `height: calc (100% - "your footer px height")` for image and for footer `"your footer px height"`

Or use js/jQuery for calculate it for yourself, thats 1 line of code

```
$(".image").css({
   height: $(window).height() - $(".footer").height()
});
```